# How to Show History of Port State/Activity?

Tags: command-line, networking, bash, ssh, history

Let's say I have an open port on my PC like `6789`. I use this port for a special purpose. But, suddenly I found the port `6789` is not listed in `netstat -ntlp` (port closed). **How can I see the history of when a port opened and closed?** Is it possible to do? It is really useful for tracing a trouble in a system.